# Can I find out through find my phone where my phone last was when the battery died?

Tags: iphone, find-my-iphone

I can't find my iphone 6 using find my phone and I am not sure if the battery has died or someone turned it off.  Is there any way to find out the last location of my iphone before the battery died or the phone was turned off?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to locate the phone unless it is more than 24 hours since it was last "spotted" by Find my iPhone. Find my iPhone deletes the locations after 24 hours.